# Create a ListView UserControl which contains Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

Multiple views in my app contain a `ListView`, the difference between them are `ItemsSource`, the `ListView` also bind some commands, the implementation of commands are same in the view-models. I want to create a `UserControl` and handle the command in the view-model of user control, this can remove lots of code in multiple views view-model.

My `UserControl` looks like this:

```
public partial class CustomListViewControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable),
         typeof(CustomListViewControl));

    public CustomListViewControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public IEnumerable MyItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(CustomListViewControl.MyItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomListViewControl.MyItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

But in the command, I need to use the `ItemsSource`. How to hook the `DependencyProperty` to a `ObservableCollection<T>` in the view-model of the `UserControl`?

Comment: Not Sure, if I understand your question, but can you not do `...MyItemSource={Binding YourObservableCollection}...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to expose a dependency property for the iCommand paramter as well as the icommand itself

```
/// <summary>
/// BUTTON COMMAND: The iCommand of the button
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public ICommand ButtonCommand {
    get { return GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomListViewControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
/// <summary>
/// BUTTON COMMAND: The iCommandParameter of the button
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public ObservableCollection<T> ButtonCommandParameter {
    get { return GetValue(ButtonCommandParameterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonCommandParameterProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCommandParameter", typeof(ObservableCollection<T>), typeof(CustomListViewControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

now you should be able to bind to the command (ButtonCommand for this example) and then bind the itemssource's observable collection of the listview to the ButtonCommandParamter.

I have used this exact approach and it worked in wpf 4.5.  I converted from VB so you might need clean this up a bit.

Hope this helps.